# Javascript Math.log() help wanted

Tags: javascript

World!

I'm trying to create a program in ***Javascript*** that takes the log of a number typed into an HTML input. Unfortunately i've encountered a problem where it wont accept the string with the *.replace()*.

Its Function:

**I.E:** When *log(10)* is calculated, the function should first remove the first 4 char's *"log("* next remove the last parenthesis *")"* and then take the log of the no. between.

HTML includes style elements, button and input form and an output < DIV >.

```
//Function
        function calculate() 
        {
            var inputString = document.getElementById("inpstr");
            var output = document.getElementById("output");

            //TESTING CODE
            /*
            if (inputString.value.startsWith("log(").endsWith(")"))
            {
                console.log(output.innerHTML = inputString.value.substring(4, 20).replace(")", ""));
            } 
                else 
            {
                output.innerHTML = "false";
            }
            */

            //Math.log() calc *****DOESNT WORK*****
            if (inputString.value.startsWith("log(").endsWith(")"))
            {
                output.innerHTML = Math.log(inputString.value.replace(")", "").substring(4, 20));
            } 
                else 
            {
                output.innerHTML = inputString.value;
            }

            event.preventDefault();
        }
```

If someone can give me an effective solution that would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Syntax

Comment: *"it wont accept the string with the .replace()."* Can you elaborate on that? Have you debugged your code and looked at the value that you are passing to `Math.log`?

Comment: You are sending a string to Math.log which require a number. You may use `parseFloat()` to convert it to a number.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm guessing I got downvoted for being lazy, so here is the quick info. Gonras got it right relating to what you want to extract, but he forgot to check that what's being input is actually a log.

That's where the regex below comes in handy! I'm matching the field to:

1. `^` start of word, since we want to match the entire field.
2. log(
3. ([-.\d]*)) any consecutive sequence (*) of numbers (\d), -, and '.', represented by the `[]`. The `\(...\)` makes sure to save this inner part for later.
4. `$` is end of word, see 1.

`res` will be `null` if there is no match. Otherwise, `res[0]` is the entire match (so the entire input field) and `res[1]` is the first 'capture group', at point 3 - which is presumably the number.

This of course fails for multiple "-" inside, or "." etc... so think it over.

```js
//Function
        function calculate() 
        {
            var inputString = document.getElementById("inpstr");
            var output = document.getElementById("output");

            var res = /^log\(([-.\d]*)\)$/.exec(inputString.value);
            if (res)
                output.innerHTML = Math.log(res[1]);
            else 
                output.innerHTML = res;
        }
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML='start';
        calculate()
```

```html
<div id='output'></div>
<input id='inpstr' value='log(2.71828)'></input>
```

If I wanted to fix your `if` to supplement Gonras's solution:

```
if (inputString.value.startsWith("log(") && inputString.value.endsWith(")"))
```

Yours fails since `startsWith()` returns a boolean, which obviously doesn't have a `endsWith` function.

Answer (score 0):

Since [Math.log()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log) accepts only number values and you're trying to pass a string to it, you should first parse this value into a float number and then pass it to the log function:

```
let val = parseFloat(inputString.value.replace(")", "").substring(4, 20));
output.innerHTML = Math.log(val);
```

Comment: I'm sure you just got it mixed up, but you meant it accepts a 'float', and wanted to use `parseFloat`.

Comment: @kabanus thanks! edited the answer. got it mixed up for sure (: